# How to show all data in highchart when having less catgories?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working with highcharts to generate graphs for my data. My doubt is the following: if I have data such as following and I know that this period is for today.

```
"data": [{
 "time": '12-10-2020 00:50:00',
 "value": 526.42
}, {
 "time": '12-10-2020 01:45:00',
 "value": 80
}, {
"time": '12-10-2020 02:47:00',
"value": 17
}, {
"time": '12-10-2020 03:52:00',
"value": 21
}, {
 "time": '12-10-2020 08:50:00',
"value": 5
 }, {
"time": '12-10-2020 09:48:00',
 "value": 5
}]
```

I approximately have my data for every hour, but the intervals are not regular so sometimes it also skips an hour or the interval may be less than an hour so I have much more data than here.
So I would like my categories to be something like `['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:07', '00:08', '09:00'...]` so it would be in total 24 labels on x axis. However, when I set my categories like this and if there is more data in series than categories not all data is shown in the graph.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate `min` and `max` properties based on your data:

```
var oneHour = 1000 * 60 * 60;

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    time: {
        useUTC: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        tickInterval: oneHour,
        min: new Date(data.data[0].time.split(' ')[0]).getTime(),
        max: (new Date(data.data[0].time.split(' ')[0]).getTime()) + oneHour * 24
    },
    series: [{
        data: data.data.map(el => [
            new Date(el.time).getTime(),
            el.value
        ])
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vzs1odqr/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.min

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max